# How to use modal pop up extender, inside the gridview image button?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, ajax

As title, how to use modal pop up extender in the gridview button.

inside the gridview, the button is just a normal button with image(i didnt use the edit template to add button).

Now what i did is (according to online source), i add an event on the gridview which is this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                (e.Row.FindControl("lnkEdit") as Button).Attributes.Add("onClick", "ShowEditModal('" + ID + "');");

            }
        }
```

Showeditmodal function is a javascript function which on the html page, but the thing is, how i am able to grab different ID from different row in the gridview, to pop up the correct modal based on the ID?

Comment: what actually the ID is? Is it a value from one of the columns of your GridView?

Comment: yes. you are right, just a value only

Comment: then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by `e.Row.Cells`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    int idColumnNumber=1; // number of your id column
                    int id=Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[idColumnNumber].Text);
                    (e.Row.FindControl("lnkEdit") as Button).Attributes.Add("onClick", "ShowEditModal('" + id + "');");

                }
            }
```